# TypeORM transaction saving entity to database despite the next transaction step failing

Tags: transactions, typeorm

I want to make a transaction to save a new table row and the many-to-many helper table entry for that row. I'm saving both using the same transaction manager but, when the second part fails, the first one isn't reverted. Why is this happening?

```
await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
    newFeed = await transactionalEntityManager
        .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into(Feed)
            .values({ ...feed })
            .execute();
    console.log('======================================\n', newFeed);
    feed.sources.forEach(async source => {
        console.log('==in forEach===\n', source.id, newFeed.identifiers[0].id);
        await transactionalEntityManager
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .insert()
            .into('feed_source')
            .values({
                sourceId: source.id,
                feedId: newFeed.identifiers[0].id,
                fontColor: feed.fontColor ? feed.fontColor : null,
                postColor: feed.postColor ? feed.postColor : null
            })
            .execute();
    });
});
```

Is it something to do with the syntax? I haven't used the insert query builder syntax before. Does .execute() somehow ignore the transaction? What's the proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I solved it. It was down to the fact that forEach seems to behave asynchronously so the code would jump to the end of the transaction before completing the loop. While looking for a solution I changed the methods I use and some of the functionality so the code ended up quite different, but the main thing is that I used Promise.all() and passed it the result of a .map() that returned promises.

```js
await getManager().transaction(async transactionalEntityManager => {
                savedFeed = await transactionalEntityManager.save(newFeed);
                if (feed.feedSources) {
                    newFeed.feedSources = [];
                    await Promise.all(
                        feed.feedSources.map(async feedSource => {
                            return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
                                const referencedSource = await Source.findOne(feedSource.sourceId);
                                console.log('===referencedSource===\n', referencedSource);
                                if (!referencedSource)
                                    throw new Error(
                                        'Could not find referenced source with id ' + feedSource.id
                                    );
                                const currentFeedSource = new FeedSource();
                                currentFeedSource.source = referencedSource;
                                currentFeedSource.feed = savedFeed;
                                feedSource.postColor
                                    ? (currentFeedSource.postColor = feedSource.postColor)
                                    : '';
                                feedSource.fontColor
                                    ? (currentFeedSource.fontColor = feedSource.fontColor)
                                    : '';
                                console.log('===currentFeedSource===\n', currentFeedSource);
                                await transactionalEntityManager.save(currentFeedSource);
                                resolve(true);
                            });
                        })
                    );
                }
```